# session.connection( ) deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm, hibernate-mapping

We moved to hibernate 4 recently. Our application has many files which has session.connection () which is deprecated. I have replaced with session.doWork() by calling like this :

```
session.doWork(new Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        wasAuto = conn.getAutoCommit();
        if(!wasAuto) {
            conn.rollback(); // in case there is existing transaction
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }

    }
});
try {
    return mainCallback.doInHibernate(session);
} finally {
    session.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            if(!wasAuto)
                conn.setAutoCommit(wasAuto);
        }
    });

}
```

But as I said we have many files having the same error. Is it a best practise to write like above.

For better understanding I'm adding one file with an error. Can someone help me in clearing the errors.

```
Session session = repo.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int recordCount = 0;
    try {
        connection = session.connection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(masterSql);
        ps.setDate(1,acctPeriod);
        ps.setLong(2,geoScheme.getId());

        recordCount = ps.executeUpdate();

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        logger.info("END --> Generating/Running Dynamic SQL for Aggregation took "+(millis / 60000.0)+" min" );
        run.addRollupMessage("Generating/Running Dynamic SQL for Aggregation took "+(millis / 60000.0)+" min" );

        run.setEndDate(DateUtils.currentTimestamp());
        logger.info("No of Loan groups inserted = " +  recordCount);
        run.addRollupMessage("No of Loan groups inserted = " +  recordCount);

    } catch (Exception err) {
        throw new RuntimeException(" **ERROR** DURING AGGREGATION: " + err.getMessage(),err);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ps != null) ps.close();
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
        if (session != null) session.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are doing your reporting via plain JDBC, I don't see a problem with just porting the code to the Work interface. In fact the Work interface is better because it looks like it will take care of closing the connection and doing the right thing if an SQL exception is thrown, so your code should be simpler.

Comment: Can u pls elaborate for me..would be grateful if u can give some code to replace in session.connection() place.

Comment: Can u pls elaborate for me..would be grateful if u can give some code to replace in session.connection() place.

Answer (score 0):

why not using spring framework and its sessionFactory component,I remember that once you init the whole factory ,you can just `session.getCurrentSession()` and that will automatically detect existed session or create a new session.

No more manual jdbc code.have fun!

Answer (score 0):

any reason you can't use this approach

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setDate(1, acctPeriod);
query.setDate(2, geoScheme.getId());
recordCount = query.executeUpdate();
```

Much simpler than anonymous classes and the like.  This will follow whatever transaction boundaries/autocommit you use with the session (whether you explicitly open a new session each time, or use spring to manage, etc...).